# Why in the calculation of large arrays the system simply hangs and doesn't raise a memory error?

Tags: python, out-of-memory

My presentation requires an out of memory system error. I would like to get it using just calculations, and not trying to open a large file.
I tried to compute a large list using comprehension:

```
ll = [x**x**x**x**x for x in range(100000)]
```

But the system just hangs and does not give any error.

Can anyone provide some advice on how to do this?

Comment: It's probably not hung, just taking so long to complete that you run out of patience and give up.  This will happen especially if you run out of physical RAM and start paging to disk.

Comment: You do realize that for x=100000 the result is 10^3125, right?

Comment: I've been waiting for over an hour!

Comment: Mark Ransom "You do realize that for x=100000 the result is 10^3125, right?" – Yes

Comment: An hour is nothing when your system is paging to disk.  The disk is over 1000 times slower than RAM.

Comment: If you just want to consume all of your available memory, why slow things down with a lengthy calculation?

Comment: If the method for getting a `MemoryError` doesn't matter, then something like `'a' * sys.maxsize` (or a large enough number) should work well without files.

Comment: Method matters. I would like to use this example to show the advantage of generators over ordinary lists.

Comment: instead of using list comprehension, just use for loop and add logger/print statement, to tell you that at what point calculation are processing/done

Comment: @Random Davis I don't need to count all these numbers - I only need a system error-memory)))

Comment: @MarkRansom: Where did you get that 10^3125 number? It's way, way more than 10^3125.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I used the log10 of 100000 and multiplication instead of exponentiation.  Maybe my math is a little sloppy.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica figured out my mistake.  I was computing `log10(x^y)` as `log10(x)*log10(y)` instead of the correct `log10(x)*y`.  You're right, I was unbelievably far off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66955235/why-in-the-calculation-of-large-arrays-of-the-system-simply-hangs-and-does-not-i#comment118352063_66955235):

> Method matters. I would like to use this example to show the advantage
> of generators over ordinary lists.

I'm not sure of the exact reason why using numbers doesn't finish-up the memory, but for your experiment:

```
ll = ['just a sample string' * x for x in range(100000)]
```

Will indeed raise a `MemoryError`, while:

```py
gen = ('just a sample string' * x for x in range(100000))
for _ in range(5):
    print(next(gen))
```

Will print:

```
just a sample string
just a sample stringjust a sample string
just a sample stringjust a sample stringjust a sample string
just a sample stringjust a sample stringjust a sample stringjust a sample string
```

and even quite fast...

Comment: Thanks for the help! I know about the magic power of generators, but in this case, I need something completely different - to get an error message about out of memory. And it is very, very, very desirable that the system does not freeze at the same time (as is happening now). Therefore, I would like the system to respond very quickly that this task is too large for its memory.

Comment: You're right! With text, not numbers, it really works! Thanks!